# Designing an item inventory system for a game and having issues

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, polymorphism, abstract

I've been working on a little inventory system just to practice my OO programming. I am using Java 7 in Netbeans.

The player will have an inventory (ArrayList of base Item Class), all items created will be a child of that base Item class.

No items should be of type BaseItem, they will all extend off of that, so to my understanding, the BaseItem class should be abstract?

```
public abstract class BaseItem {
    protected GoldValue itemValue;
    protected String itemName;

    //accessors and mutators down here
}
```

Child item types will also have different properties, which I was going to implement as Interfaces, such as Stackable, Consumable, etc.

The interface looks something like this

```
public interface Stackable {   

    public void stack (StackableItem bi1);

}
```

As you can see, I make a reference to StackableItem here, that is one of the children of BaseItem, which is also abstract and specific items will build out of.

```
public abstract class StackableItem extends BaseItem implements Stackable{

    protected int quantity;
    protected int maxStacks;

    @Override
    public void stack (StackableItem si)
    {
        if(this.getQuantity() + si.getQuantity() < maxStacks){
            this.setQuantity(this.getQuantity()+si.getQuantity());
            si.setQuantity(0);
        }
        else if(this.getQuantity() + si.getQuantity() > maxStacks){
            int diff = maxStacks - this.getQuantity();
            this.setQuantity(this.getQuantity() + diff);
            si.setQuantity(si.getQuantity() - diff);
        }
    }
}
```

and here's an example of a specific item:

```
public class StackableItemExample extends StackableItem{

    public StackableItemExample ()throws GoldException
    {
        this(new GoldValue(0,0,0), "unnamed", 1);
    }
    public StackableItemExample(GoldValue gv, String name, int quan) throws GoldException
    {
        this.itemValue = gv;
        this.itemName = name;
        this.quantity = quan;
        this.maxStacks = 10;
        this.itemValue.setGoldValue(gv.getGold()*quan, gv.getSilver()*quan, gv.getCopper()*quan);
    }


}
```

My `Inventory`, being an `ArrayList` of `BaseItem` objects, is allowed to have a `StackableItemExample` object inserted into it no problem.  The issue is, my inventory system cannot say `BaseItem.stack()` since the parent has no knowledge of this method.

I want to make a very easily extendable item system, that a new item can be created with extreme simplicity by implementing and extending pre-created classes and interfaces, but this is getting in my way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No items should be of type BaseItem, they will all extend off of that, so to my understanding, the BaseItem class should be abstract?**

Sounds good to me

---

If you want `BaseItem.stack()` to work, you could do at least two things:

- Move `stack()` into your base class, and give it a default implementation of doing nothing.  Then override that in your StackableItem class, or
- Use `instanceof` to see whether the BaseItem is a StackableItem, then cast it to a StackableItem and go from there.

The second approach would look like:

```
BaseItem item = YourList.get(i);
if(item instanceof StackableItem){
    StackableItem stackable = (StackableItem)item;
    stackable.stack()  /* Now works without issue */
}
```

Comment: I'll give it a try, but is there a possibility that some data will be lost in the casting?
What I'm asking is, does item still have the values of the StackableItem class, but are just not visible when using Item.<field> or Item.<method>()?  If so, then this works perfectly!

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how it works (and no, no data will be lost).  You don't lose the additional information about the object -- it's runtime type is remains whatever you created it as.  You just can't access those members/methods unless you first cast it to the appropriate subclass.

Comment: Awesome, this should work perfectly.  Any warnings with doing it this way though? Type casting an object seems really risky, but as long as we use instanceof, we should be ok?

Comment: Casting in java is "safer" than it is in other languages.  The code listed is a common way to handle the case where you have a base-type collection of objects and want to operate on additional functionality provided by the various subclasses.  And `instanceof` protects you from getting `ClassCastException`s.

Answer (score -1):

Make every item Stackable - currently unstackable items should have a stack size of one. You could then get rid of the stackable abstract class and interface, putting that functionality into the base class.

Comment: Unfortunately, this type of implementation probably wont work with other Item Properties, such as Edible